Payment system in Bigquery issue OR-CBAT-19
When I try to register in the Bigquery I get "This action couldn't be completed. Try again with a different payment method. Learn more [OR-CBAT-19]". What should I do in this case?
I hope you can support me in this problem.

Hi @Сергій Красовський, Did you set up the billing account with the GCP ?, Also have a look at this stack link. Let me know if this helped you or not.
